# I messed up Xcode somehow

Tags: ios, xcode

So I'm learning Objective-C and making iOS apps, but I seem to have done something to Xcode and everything looks all messed up.

Here's what I'm talking about:

- The UIViewController / StoryBoard is WAY to wide, it auto-sizes to that right when I begin a new project:
  [image: Screenshot]
- I'm missing the items like "New UIView Controller" and stuff, I've searched every tab:
  [image: Screenshot]

EDIT: All issues have been fixed, but when I add a new UIViewController, I don't get the ViewController, just the files!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Just use Xcode 5 and you are OK. Wide Storyboards are new feature, I recommend watching WWDC videos.

Answer (score 1):

For your first "issue":

From what I've seen in a WWDC movie, this is the 'universal' view of a Storyboard, which is device-agnostic.

I believe you can select a specific device in the bottom of the UI, where it says 'Any'.

Comment: Thanks! This helped, but I still don't have the regular options like I should :(

Comment: I advise you to take some time and watch the 'What's new in Xcode' movie of the WWDC.

Answer (score 0):

> The UIViewController / StoryBoard is WAY to wide, it auto-sizes to
>   that right when I begin a new project:

You can simply zoom-out using `Editor > Canvas > Zoom > Zoom out` or by using your touchpad or by using the shortcut `Alt + Cmd + 8`.

> I'm missing the items like "New UIView Controller" and stuff, I've
>   searched every tab:

You simply create a new `Cocoa Touch Class` and in the next prompt you will be asked for the desired subclass. You type in: `UIViewController`.

> EDIT: All issues have been fixed, but when I add a new
>   UIViewController, I don't get the ViewController, just the files!

So with you "don't get" you mean that your ViewController in the Interace Builder is not yet connected to your "files", right? Just click on your designated ViewController in Interace Builder and press `Alt + Cmd + 3` to open the third Inspector-Tab and type in your class name "dashboard" into the first textfield.

Comment: No problem ;) If your problem is solved It would be great you mark my answer as the accepted one and/or vote it up.

Comment: I have one last error, do you think you could help with that?

Comment: Just did that, no results came up.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the size of the storyboard device by clicking on wAny hAny button at the bottom middle of xcode.